# Actualizar datos con espacios en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Tengo una base de datos, con un par de tablas en las cuales he almacenado muchos registros que han sido traídos de otra base de datos.

Mi gran inconveniente es que los datos han pasado con espacios, antes del dato real, pareciera que sql server tomara este espacio como un carácter, ya que al consultarlo no aparece. Mi pregunta es: ¿Existe alguna forma de actualizar todos estos datos y quitarles este espacio?

añado imagen para complementar mi problema
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el campo en el cual se presenta el inconveniente es *codigo1*

Comment: tal vez `UPDATE tabla SET codigo1=RTRIM(LTRIM(codigo1))`?  para quitar espacios a derecha e izquierda.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho a la izquierda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sobre tu inquietud puedes resolverla usando funciones de t-sql como LTRIM y RTRIM de la siguiente manera:

```
UPDATE TuTabla SET Codigo1 = LTRIM(RTRIM(Codigo1));
```

al realizar este proceso de update va a retirar los espacios en blanco que existan en las columnas.

Otra posibilidad es que hagas un replace en tu consulta para que cuando se ejecuta la consulta reemplace los campos por un comodín como es un "-" en lugar de los espacios en blanco, de esta forma ya no tendrías espacios en blanco en tu consulta, ademas sobre la consulta recuerda el comando like con sus comodines "%tuValor%" si es una cadena lo que estas comparando.

Espero te sea de utilidad, saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias me ha sido de gran utilidad su comando.